# Good practice if I need to add interfaces on generated hibernate Pojo

Tags: java, hibernate, pojo

Here is my situation, I'm working with hibernate, and the database schema will still be changing in the futur.
So everytime the schema is changed, I regenerate my hibernate objects from the database schema.
The problem with this approach is that I can't add interfaces on my objects, or they'd be reset the next time I generate objects.

Modifying the objects manually when changes are made on the database doesn't seems obtimal either.
Other solution is to generate the pojos in a seperate place, then merge them... That can be a bit painful but it's a solution.

So is there a good approach regarding the modification of generated Pojos?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just extend your generated objects and add the interfaces to them, or better wrap your generated classes in another class.

Comment: It seems to be the best way to go!
Thanks a lot!